# Qt: resize MainWindow and its contents according to the resolution of monitor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qgraphicsview, qwidget

I want to display MainWindow, in full screen and its contents should resize accordingly to the size of the monitor:

My `MainWindow.ui`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>820</width>
    <height>651</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>metaio SDK – Qt Tutorials</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="layoutDirection">
    <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
   </property>
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="mainLayout">
      <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
       <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>1300</width>
          <height>768</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="resizeAnchor">
         <enum>QGraphicsView::NoAnchor</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="buttonLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="quitTutorialButton">
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <weight>75</weight>
            <bold>true</bold>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>« Back</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
 <slots>
  <slot>on_load_arel()</slot>
  <slot>on_load_file()</slot>
  <slot>on_close_tab(int)</slot>
  <slot>on_save_and_preview()</slot>
  <slot>on_preview_channel()</slot>
 </slots>
</ui>
```

some code of my `MainWindow.cpp`:

```
...
setupUi(this);

quitTutorialButton->setVisible(false);

QObject::connect(quitTutorialButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onQuitTutorialButtonClicked()));

m_pMenu = new Menu(this, this);

// Init the main view for the scene using OpenGL
QGLWidget *glWidget = new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers));
m_pGraphicsView = graphicsView;
m_pGraphicsView->setScene(m_pMenu);
m_pGraphicsView->setViewport(glWidget);
m_pGraphicsView->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
```

some code in my `Menu.cpp`:

```
m_pWebView = new QGraphicsWebView();
addItem(m_pWebView);
m_pWebView->resize(1300, 768); // dont want this to be static

QObject::connect(m_pWebView, SIGNAL(linkClicked(const QUrl&)), this, SLOT(linkClicked(const QUrl&)));

QTimer::singleShot(20, this, SLOT(loadContent()));
```

Please help me out.

**Edit:**

If you see, i have added `QGraphicsWebView` programatically. I am running this solution on my notebook, with 1366 x 768 resolution. If i want to use entire screen space, i have to give size to my `QGraphicsWebView` (line with comment added at the end) and to my `QGraphicsView` that lies in my `MainWindow.ui`. I want to remove this static part, and make it dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `QLayout` managers then all you should need to do is set the window state to full screen: [QWidget::setWindowState](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#setWindowState). The layout managers should take care of the rest, most likely you'll need to set the spacing and use some `QSpacers` to get the elements exactly where you want them.

Comment: Have you tried calling `QGraphicsView::fitInView`? You should be able to pass a `QRect` of the area you want when the `QMainWindow` is resized to resize the `QGraphicsView`.

Comment: Sir, i am a newbie to Qt. If you don't mind can you write me the corrections to be made, i would be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

About the fullscreen issue: have you tried with [QMainWindow::showFullScreen()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#showFullScreen) ?

**Reply to the edit:**

I don't see any reason for those nested layouts, it is kinda messed up. Instead of having

```
-- mainLayout
 |-- graphicsView
 |-- buttonLayout <- why layout only one element??
   |-- quitTutorialButton
```

try with this simpler layout

```
-- mainLayout
 |-- graphicsView
 |-- quitTutorialButton
```

Then, **change** the fixed size policy to `MinimumExpanding` instead.

Last advice: since looks like you layout your items by hand, **never** insert the outermost layout by hand. If you do so, the elements in it will never scale to the QMainWindow size.

Instead, right-click in an empty portion of the central widget, select `Layout` and then choose the type of layout you want to apply. This of course is needed only for the outmost layout: for the remaining, inner ones, you can add them by simple drag&drop as usual.